# Is there something like a global chat?

Tags: clash-royale

I  think I read something about a global chat in Clash Royale like it is implemented in its big brother Clash of Clans. However, I can't find it anywhere inside the app.

I somehow miss this feature especially for advertising for the own clan. Was it not implemented in Clash Royale and if yes are there statements about a future update?

Maybe there are also players, who played CoC from the beginning, how has it been there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no Global Chat.  There have been discussions of such feature on the Supercell Forum, but the idea has been ruled out.

A possible reason for not having Global Chat might be to cut back on spam and inappropriate language, as Clash of Clans contains a fair amount.  Although this causes some issues with recruitment, people can use the forums as recruiting center in place of a Global Chat.

Answer (score 1):

So far **No** The next best thing you can use, to promote your clan and what not is use the [forums](http://forum.supercell.net/forumdisplay.php/107-Clash-Royale)